# Sort matrix by colnames from another matrix

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, matrix

I have two matrices with the same dimensions and they both have the same stock names as colnames, but in a different order!

I would like to sort the matrix "A" by the colnames of the matrix "B".

So the A colnames and the according value should be in the same order as the colnames of B.

How can I do this?

Example:
[image]

Kind Regards

Comment: More importantly than any other tag, always add `r`. Otherwise your questions are very likely to remain unnoticed. Also, pictures like this are rarely helpful and instead you should provide chunks of code that can be copied and directly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example in R terms would be

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 4, 2), nrow = 1)
colnames(A) <- c("B", "D", "E")
A
#      B D E
# [1,] 1 4 2

B <- matrix(c(2, 5, 1), nrow = 1)
colnames(B) <- c("E", "B", "D")
B
#      E B D
# [1,] 2 5 1
```

Then we may simply subset the columns of `A` in the same order as they are in `B`:

```
A[, colnames(B)]
# E B D 
# 2 1 4
```

Comment: Oh Lord! Thank you for the advice regarding the tag! This is so easy. I just subset the matrix with the colnames from the other matrix and it worked. Thank you so much!